# Unable to load libraries(.so files) in System Application

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libs

My application works fine if i install it as a **Normal application**. When i tried to make my application as a **System App** its failing to load the **native libraries**.

Following are the steps followed in order to make my application as System App.

1) Rooted my device

2) placed my **.apk file in system/app folder**.

My app will be installed as a System App but it crashes on launch as it is not getting libraries(.so files).

I Tried doing the following things in order to resolve the issue

1) Extracted my .apk file and copied the libs from my .apk file to **System/libs** folder but it didnt work.

2)Extracted my .apk file and copied the libs from my .apk file to **data/data/com.myapp.packagename** folder but it didnt work.

3) Tried changing the the default allocated permissions 600 to 755 but it didnt work.

4)If i comment out the library loading code in my application, the application runs successfully.

Comment: Could be an issue with 64 or 32-bit libs.

Comment: It looks you are asking duplicate questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746914/do-i-need-to-copy-so-files-to-system-libs .  I have answered there