# Do i need to copy .so files to System/libs?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-native-interface, native

I want to make my application as a system application. But my application crashes when i make it as system app (placed .apk file inside System/app).
It crashes because its not able to load .so files.

My first question here is do i need to copy the libs( Extract .apk and i will be getting libs) inside System/libs or the System automatically does it?

My Second question here is does the system load libraries(.so files) from System/libs or data/data/myApp.PackageName/lib folder?

Any Help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question here is do i need to copy the libs( Extract .apk and i will be getting libs) inside System/libs or the System automatically does it?

You don't need to manually copy the `.so` files.

But, please double check why

> It crashes because its not able to load .so files.

you need to ensure that you have the corresponding **ABI** for your target phone, e.g. you need to have `arm64-v8a` for your real devices, but this ABI **won't work for emulators** as usually emulators are `x86` or `x86_64`.

> My Second question here is does the system load libraries(.so files) from System/libs or data/data/myApp.PackageName/lib folder?

From data/data/myApp.PackageName/lib